# PHP - mysqli_query not providing error

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am writing a script that uses data from the user to create a page and create a database entry for the created page. Unfortunately, despite the fact that the query I am using was generated by `phpmyadmin`, the insert does not succeed.

I have attempted using both `mysql` and `mysqli` for all of the function calls(not at the same time obviously) but have received the same result regardless.

While I would love to understand why the insert is failing the more pressing issue is the fact that no error is being produced.

The error conditional is being entered but both `mysql_error()` and `mysqli_error()` end up empty.

This is the segment of code where the error occurs:

```
$result = mysqli_query($pvcon,"'INSERT INTO content 
        (content.post_type_id,
        content.content_title,
        content.content_description,
        content.content_link,
        content.user_id,
        content.content_image_path,
        content.date_posted) 
        values (\'".$post_type."\', 
        \'".$title."\', 
        \'".$description."\', 
        \'".$content_link."\', 
        \'".$user_id."\', 
        \'".urlencode($article_image)."\', 
        now())'");
        if (!$result) {
            echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
            exit;
        }
```

I have found multiple questions that are similar to mine but none of those solutions have worked for me which leads me to believe that there is some simple step that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($pvcon,"'INSERT INTO content 
                               ^---
   ..... snip....
        now())'");
              ^----
```

your entire query is wrong - you've enclosed it in `'`-quotes, making the ENTIRE query a monolithic string. And your error call never works, because you've forgotten to include the link identifier in the call:

```
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($pvcon);
                                    ^^^^^^--missing.
```

Plus, given the variable names you're using, you're probably ALSO vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, so enjoy having your server pwn3d on top of all this.